# Непонятки с RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc

Есть метод в контроллере

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home/home",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
    model.addObject("msg", new Date());
    return model;
}
```

Также есть файл `home.jsp` в каталоге `/WEB-INF/jsp/`. Когда ввожу в url строку типа `http://localhost:8080/Имя_Проекта/home/home` glassfish выкидывает resource not found. Подскажите где косяк. Буду признателен если распишите на пальцах как работает RequestMapping и ModelAndView

Comment: Попробуйте развернуть в контейнере полегче: Jetty или Tomcat,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы Spring находил ваши jsp не по полному пути, а просто по имени нужно настроить сопоставление имени и пути к файлу.

Для этого в контексте должен лежать `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

---

Минимальный работающий пример:

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```xml
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servle.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp**

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h1>message: ${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**com.springapp.mvc.HelloController**

```java
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home/home")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello world!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: это все сделано